# Acra: install, extend Application - Activity?

Tags: android, acra

I am trying to install the ACRA crash report system to my android project. Now, my project is already extending a class, the Activity class. How can I implement the Acra project then?

As they state in normal way, you have to make a class f.e. MyApplication and extend it with Application. Since I am already extending the Activity class I am not sure what to do... They say: If your app already contains an Application subclass, add ACRA to this class; however, I don't know how I should do this..

Thanks!

http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

Answer (score 2):

Just create a `MyApplication` class that extends from `Application`, do what they say about overriding `onCreate()` and then go to your AndroidManifest.

You should have an `<application>` with values such as `android:label` or `android:theme`. Just add `android:name=".MyApplication"` there and you're ready to go.

Have in mind that if your package is `com.example.test`, `MyApplication` has to be there. If you want to put MyApplication wherever else, you must point to where it is.

For example, if your package is `com.example.test` and `MyApplication` is in `com.example.test.application`, you must add `android:name=".application.MyApplication` to your manifest. I strongly reccomend you to use a package just for your Application, as it atomizes your project and makes it far more manageable and mantainable.

Comment: Well I did just that and the first thing I notice is that my app isnt working anymore... :s

09-11 11:00:36.682: W/dalvikvm(6090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
09-11 11:00:36.682: E/ACRA(6090): ACRA caught a RuntimeException exception for com.droid. Building report.

Comment: Is there a "Caused by: ...." with another nested exception in the stacktrace ? This should give you an idea of what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Application is used because of the manifest. In the manifest, it is just to add this to the application tag(with all activities inside):

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Ex:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Because of the easy initialization(as it is automatically initialized by the Android System on launch) it will **never not report**. It can crash instantly on startup and still report. So it is a really smart setup.

My application class looks like this:

```
@ReportsCrashes(

    formUri = "https://backend.com",
    customReportContent = { /* */ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,ReportField.LOGCAT },
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text

)  

public class ACRAHandler extends Application {


    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);


        final ACRAConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder(this)

                .build();
        // Initialise ACRA
        ACRA.init(this, config);

    }



}
```

If you for an instance are using Firebase, you can use both together in the same application-extending class without any issues. I tried it myself and it worked, no problems with error reporting or Firebase.

Additionally, the new links for ACRA is now on Github: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

I answered this because it was so long ago the answers came and it needs an update

Answer (score -1):

An application sub class is required to maintain a global application state, it is not necessary for every app to sub class it. If you app does not have one yet, you can create it.

Example:

```
/* do ACRA imports */
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "x-x-x-x-x-x")
public class YourApplication extends Application{

public void onCreate(){
    ACRA.init(this);
    super.onCreate();
}
}
```

you should also declare in the manifest file as stated in the tutorial.